# Trouble starting apache karaf.bat (Karaf 3.0.0)

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I have properly set up `JAVA_HOME`, `MAVEN_HOME` to point to jdk home and maven installation homedirectory, and have also added `JAVA_HOME/bin` and `MAVEN_HOME/bin` in the `PATH`. But still when I execute `karaf.bat` I ***don't see*** any output as mentioned in the [quick start guide here](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/quick-start.html). Instead I see blank screen infinitely running. Please help me.

I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some google search, found [this mail archive](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/karaf-user/201401.mbox/%3CCAAM=DsPm7jFuqkDZk4oDS5hoFMEFVrOp6LHgSwtrPwY-_7SOhA@mail.gmail.com%3E), which says the downloaded karaf could be corrupt.

As guided I downloaded the fresh karaf zip from another mirror (other than previously downloaded mirror) and now after installation, I am able to successfully run `karaf.bat`

Answer (score 0):

I encounted the same problem. Apparently Karaf didn't start as it was described in the tutorial. Even more confusing was the fact that the log showed normal. Java process was created, the log said nothing wrong but Karaf console was silent.
After I tried to debug the problem for a while, I've discovered that downloading the zip from a different mirror solved the problem.